# Чем отличается project от targets

Tags: xcode

чем отличается project от targets

вопрос у меня возник, когда я заметил что Build Settings есть и там и там, так в чём же разница, обьясните)))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проект - всё что у тебя есть(файлы, ресурсы).

Цели ты создаешь сам, их может быть несколько.

Каждая цель имеет возможность индивидуального подбора файлов и ресурсов для компилиции варианта твоего продукта(настройка- тыкаешь файл, далее выбираешь в панели справа вместо quick help - file inspector, там есть группа target membership где и определяешь к какой цели относится данный файл).

Comment: хороший, и развернутый ответ. +1

Answer (score 0):

В рамках одного проекта таргеты могут использовать общие сорсы для компиляции. 
Посмотри TargetMembership для любого файла проекта.